# webpack config in server production

Tags: webpack, redux

I am new to **webpack**, i have a project **redux+webpack**, everything go well locally, such as `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, but when I push my project to a remote server, the server can not find the files which are in the 'public' folder, this folder is where it serves the bundles (js, css, etc), this is my config file

```
var path = require('path');
var rtlcss = require('rtlcss');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var deepmerge = require('deepmerge');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var blessPlugin = require('bless-webpack-plugin');
var webpackCommonConfig = require('./webpack.common');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

var sourceMap = false;

if (process.env.SOURCEMAP === 'true') {
  sourceMap = true;
}

var wds = {
  hostname: process.env.WP_HOST || "localhost",
  port: process.env.WP_PORT || 8079
};

var wdsPath = "http://" + wds.hostname + ":" + wds.port;
var publicPath = wdsPath + "/assets/";

var devtool = '';
var entry = {
  'app': ['./src/main.js'],
  'main': ['./sass/main.scss'],
  'main-rtl': ['./sass/main.rtl.scss'],
  'plugins': ['./src/plugins.js']
};

var plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({__CLIENT__: true, __SERVER__: false, __PRODUCTION__: isProduction, __DEV__: !isProduction, "process.env.NODE_ENV": '"'+process.env.NODE_ENV+'"', __DEVTOOLS__: true}),
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/vertx/)
];

if (process.env.EXTRACT_TEXT_PLUGIN === 'true') {
  plugins.unshift(new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css'));
  plugins.unshift(blessPlugin({ imports: true, compress: true }));
}

if (isProduction) {
  plugins.unshift(new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin());
  plugins.unshift(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
  plugins.unshift(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    mangle: false,
    compress: {
      unused: false,
      warnings: false
    },
    sourceMap: sourceMap
  }));
} else {
  plugins.unshift(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
}

function getStyleLoader(prefixer) {
  var s = '';

  if (sourceMap) s = 'sourceMap';

  if (process.env.EXTRACT_TEXT_PLUGIN === 'false') {
    return [
      'style',
      'css?-minimize&importLoaders=1&root=../public&' + s,
      'postcss-loader?pack='+prefixer+'!sass?' + s
    ];
  }

  return [
    ExtractTextPlugin.loader({
      extract: true,
      omit: 1
    }),
    'style',
    'css?-minimize&importLoaders=1&' + s,
    'postcss-loader?pack='+prefixer+'&' + s,
    'sass?' + s
  ];
}

devtool = sourceMap ? 'source-map' : '';

if (!isProduction) {
  for (var key in entry) {
    if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      entry[key].push("webpack/hot/only-dev-server");
    }
  }

  entry.app.unshift("react-hot-loader/patch");

  entry.devServerClient = "webpack-dev-server/client?" + wdsPath;
}

var ltrloaders = getStyleLoader('normalprefixer');
var rtlloaders = getStyleLoader('rtlprefixer');

if (process.env.RTL !== 'true') {
  rtlloaders = ['null-loader'];
}

var loaders = webpackCommonConfig.module.loaders.concat();
// ltr/rtl loaders
loaders.push({ test: function(absPath) {
  if (absPath.search('rtl.scss') !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}, loaders: rtlloaders });
loaders.push({ test: function(absPath) {
  if (absPath.search('rtl.scss') === -1
   && absPath.search('.scss') !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}, loaders: ltrloaders });

// script loader for plugins.js
var pluginLoaders = ['script'];
if (isProduction) {
  pluginLoaders.push('uglify');
}
loaders.push({
  test: /(\/|\\)public(\/|\\)(.*?)\.js$/,
  loaders: pluginLoaders
});

delete webpackCommonConfig.module;

module.exports = deepmerge({
  cache: true,
  debug: true,
  devtool: devtool,
  entry: entry,
  module: {
    loaders: loaders
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return {
      normalprefixer: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 9'] }) ],
      rtlprefixer: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 9'] }), rtlcss ]
    };
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: wdsPath,
    publicPath: publicPath,
    hot:        true,
    inline:     false,
    lazy:       false,
    quiet:      true,
    noInfo:     true,
    headers:    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    stats:      { colors: true },
    host:       wds.hostname,
    port:       wds.port
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'public'),
    publicPath: isProduction ? '/' : publicPath,
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },
  plugins: plugins,
}, webpackCommonConfig);
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: You might have to paste the difference in the `urls` between your dev and prod environments to be of more help. The usual way of dealing with this is having a different config for dev and prod.
For example, for my development environment `webpack.publichPath = '/static'`, so my prod environment `webpack.publicPath = '/apps/static'`.

A good way to differentiate is to use different config files while building or check for `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` in your webpack.config if you're running webpack like `NODE_ENV=production webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

> I appreciate any help

If folder structure has not been modified, when web-application had been deployed to server, just use `__dirname`-based relative paths, which will be invariant relative to current working directory. By importing `path` module, just resolve all paths to server-absolute in compile time by construction `const relpath = path.join(__dirname, "./relative/path")`.

Also you can specify custom [external resource resolvers](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), which will link real resources with `webpack` aliases on runtime, so any real search can be performed:

```
externals: [
  function(context, request, callback) {
    if (/^yourregex$/.test(request)){
      return callback(null, 'commonjs ' + request);
    }
    callback();
  }
],
```